# Mysql min and max values and corresponding "date" for each month

Tags: mysql, date, max, minimum

I have a table named "rates" and it has two fields "date" and "rate". I like to get MIN and MAX rate values and their dates on which they occurred for each month. But I could not manage.

> SELECT  date,
>   MIN(rate) AS minRate,
>   MAX(rate) AS maxRate,
>   MONTH(date) AS monthName,
>   YEAR(date) AS yearName
>   FROM rates
>   GROUP BY  yearName ASC, monthName ASC

**Clarification:** I  like to get something like this:

```
 Months  MIN    mindate     MAX      maxdate  
 Jan     1.234  2012-01-13   1.534  2012-01-24  
 Feb     1.165  2012-02-28   1.373  2012-02-11
```

and so on

Comment: you mean by ORDER BY yearName ASC , monthName ASC ? GROUP BY doesn't need ASC / DESC

Comment: I want to get MIN rate and its date on the same row and MAX rate and its date on the same row. And I want to show all months' min and max values of course.

Comment: could you provide input to the table too??

Comment: `GROUP BY yearName ASC, monthName ASC ` won't work... It should be `GROUP BY yearName, monthName ORDER BY yearName, monthName`

Comment: @Rocky It doesn't need here since it's ASC which is default. But GROUP BY can indeed have DESC. In MySQL a GROUP BY implies an ORDER BY

Comment: @FahimParkar see my comment above to Rocky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query, the database name is test, you can use yours or remove it:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(rate) AS minRate,
  (select date from test.rates where rate = min(co.rate) and  
    month(date) = month(co.date) and year(date) = year(co.date) limit  
  )as min_date,
  MAX(rate) AS maxRate,
  (select date from test.rates where rate = max(co.rate) and  
    month(date) = month(co.date) and year(date) = year(co.date) limit 1) as 
  max_date
FROM test.rates co 
GROUP BY year(date) , month(date)
```