# SELECT name using MIN and MAX - mysql

Tags: mysql

So I want to be able to show the most expensive movie to rent and the least expensive movie to rent. Basically I want to show the movie title along with its price. Now I am able to get the highest and lowest rental price with this query:

```
SELECT MAX(rental_rate) as MaxRate, MIN(rental_rate) as MinRate 
FROM film;
```

However how do I edit that query above to show the movie titles in relation to their rates?

I have also tried:

```
SELECT title (SELECT MAX(rental_rate) FROM film as MaxRate),
             (SELECT MIN(rental_rate) FROM film as MinRate)
FROM film;
```

But that did not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Essentially the same problem as [Mysql min and max values and corresponding "date" for each month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411767/mysql-min-and-max-values-and-corresponding-date-for-each-month), although that one has dates instead of titles.

Comment: Alternate query that worked for me but this question got closed.


    select title, rental_price from films
    where 
        (rental_price  = (SELECT MAX(rental_price) FROM films as MaxRate ) or 
        rental_price = (SELECT MIN(rental_price) FROM films as MinRate));

sqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b2eb4/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper solution can be found in the question I referred to in comments, but it is a bit complex. I think another, simpler solution would be to `ORDER BY` rate and use `LIMIT` to get 1 record. You can use `UNION` to combine two similar queries to get the lowest and highest rate:

```
(SELECT title, rental_rate 
FROM film
ORDER BY rental_rate 
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT title, rental_rate 
FROM film
ORDER BY rental_rate DESC
LIMIT 1)
```

`UNION ALL` could be used too, but then you could get the same title if the table contains only one film.

Note that this query will return one lowest rate title and one highest rate title. If you want all titles that share the lowest or highest rate, you'll need [that other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411767/mysql-min-and-max-values-and-corresponding-date-for-each-month).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is two rows with different conditions, so keep them separate:

```
(SELECT title, rental_rate, "most expensive" as which_title 
from film
ORDER BY rental_rate DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT title, rental_rate, "least expensive" from film
ORDER BY rental_rate ASC LIMIT 1)
```

with working sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e290/3

Comment: I think it's not as simple as that. This query gives you the lowest and highest rate and a random title to go with each of them.

Comment: @GolezTrol right you are

Answer (score 0):

you can also use below query if you want the min and max of rates with the title of them:

```
select title, (SELECT MAX(rental_rate) FROM film) from film
       where rental_rate=(SELECT MAX(rental_rate) FROM film)

union

select title, (SELECT MIN(rental_rate) FROM film) from film
       where rental_rate=(SELECT MIN(rental_rate) FROM film)
```